# What are the "kviews"?

Tags: support, views

What is the meaning of the `kviews` unit used on Stack Overflow??

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thousand views.

If you hover over the number, there is a tooltip with the exact number of views.

Comment: It's interesting how it seems that some questions have a handful of views and some have thousands, and there don't seem to be many with views in between.

Comment: @Peter - One factor could be that people see a question with a relatively high view count and want to see what everyone found so interesting, which bumps up the view count, which makes more people want to see what's so interesting, which...

Comment: @ChrisF, @Peter - Other factor is also that there are the questions seen by only people on the trilogy, even if several of them, and there are the questions answering to a frequent google request.

Comment: @Peter - Take a look at [Scale Free Networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-free_network). You have noticed a phenomenon that is characteristic of many/most social networks as well as web-based media.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602193/the-sybase-ase-ole-db-provider-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine  
11k Views in 2 minutes??