# What are the kviews next to my Asked Questions?

Tags: support, views

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what are the kviews?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55109/what-are-the-kviews)

I apologize if this is a rudimentary question, but what do the kviews next to the list of my questions mean?

Comment: Belongs on http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K symbolizes three zeroes (000). See: [SI prefix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_prefix)

So 1k would be 1000 views/votes anything.

The confusing part and I will (eventually post a request on meta about this) that this might be confusing since 1 kviews means nothing actually, and should be 1k views.

(Though most people do understand)

Is it clearer now?

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

1 kview = 1 kiloview = 1000 views